# Volley is not connecting to node.js service?

Tags: android, node.js, android-volley

I have created a node.js rest web service on my local host and simpleandroid application with a button ,
My service is up and when i use postman to test service it works perfectly but when i use my android app it doesn't  connect to my service
here is my android code

```
 btnCTime.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View vw) {
                String Url = "http://localhost:3000/users";
                String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";
                JsonObjectRequest jsonReqObj = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                                                                    Url,(String)null,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                //VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                                // hide the progress dialog
                                if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError)
                                {
                                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: Timeout" );
                                } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: AuthFailureError" );
                                    //TODO
                                } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: ServerError" );
                                    //TODO
                                } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: NetworkError" );
                                    //TODO
                                } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: ParseError" );
                                    //TODO
                                }
                            }
                        });
                // Adding request to request queue
                AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReqObj, tag_json_obj);

            }
        });
```

and this is the output when i run the android app

```
06-27 00:41:47.566 2248-2248/com.my.google.roshan_.app79 D/Volley: [1] 2.onErrorResponse:
```

Comment: `http://localhost:3000/users` is probably the issue. Can you change it to a LAN IP address? `localhost/127.0.0.1` is connecting to itself, so unless you're also running a node.js server on your android device, it's not going to work. You need to use the address of the computer that is running the server.

Comment: @DaveChen Thanks i have got the machin ip and now working fine.again thankzz

Answer (score 0):

As DaveChen said  when i type localhost on an android device it search it's own server , i used Commandline in my laptop and got ip address using `ipconfig` 
and replaced localhost from machine IP.